# Failed to load viewstate. Error occurred only in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, internet-explorer

I am using ASP.Net 4.0 and it throws an error only in a single page and single browser. This error occurs only IE whenever in other browsers i.e. (Chrome, firefox, safari, opera) in all of them this page runs properly and working fine but this page gives an error in and only in IE when we call any button event of this page in IE but if we are using other than IE it works fine. I am too much stuck why this error occurs only in IE and i tried lots to getting this error but i failed. Can anyone help me out i am describing this error information:

> Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is
>   being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save
>   viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding
>   controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match
>   the type and position of the controls added during the initial
>   request.  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.

Exception Details:

> System.Web.HttpException: Failed to load viewstate.
>   The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the
>   control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous
>   request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls
>   added during a post-back must match the type and position of the
>   controls added during the initial request.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to load viewstate.  The control
>   tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree
>   that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For
>   example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a
>   post-back must match the type and position of the controls added
>   during the initial request.]
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState) +327
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadChildViewStateByIndex(ArrayList childState)
>   +148    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState) +225
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadChildViewStateByIndex(ArrayList childState)
>   +148    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState) +225    System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +312
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +747

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Care to show the code that raises the error?

Comment: Which IE version, what and how dynamic controls are done and do you have any update panels in there ?

Comment: i check this on IE-7,8,9 all versions and throws this error on all browsers...

Comment: are you adding any control dynamically in your code?

Comment: @BrijeshMishra: No i am not using any dynamic control in this page there are all static controls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable ViewState for this page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind=" #####.aspx.cs" Inherits="#####"  EnableViewState="false"%>
```

Comment: I am wondering how we find what it really causes this problem